# WordPress Comments sort by custom meta key

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, sort, comments

I want to sort comments by a number of likes which is saved as a meta_key in the wp_commentmeta table: I have tried two ways but it doesn't sort the comments by most liked comment at the top. Please suggest the solution:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'comment',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'callback' => 'listingo_comments',
    'meta_key' => 'cld_like_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'    => 'DESC'             
);

wp_list_comments($args);
```

// and second way

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'post_type'     => 'comment',
                        'callback'      => 'listingo_comments',
                        'orderby'       => 'cld_like_count',
                        'order'         => 'DESC'
                        ));

     wp_list_comments($query);
```

Comment: Do you have a post type with the slug `comment`? If not, use the *first method* and remove the `'post_type' => 'comment',`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I do not have post type with the slug comment. I tried the first method by removing 'post_type' => 'comment' but still the order of comments does not change

Comment: Thanks! Sally, it sorts the comment now. But there is one problem it lists comment that has some value in cld_like_count meta_key. How can I add Zero '0' to this meta_key whenever there is a new comment. So that it lists all comments for the post and later users can like or dislike that comment.

Comment: $args = get_comments(array(

'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
'meta_key' => 'cld_like_count'
));

wp_list_comments(array(
'callback' => 'listingo_comments',), $args);                                                           
                                                                                                                              Or can we make changes to this code to list all comments with or without having any values in cld_like_count meta_key.

Comment: anyone knows how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, @EmmaB, I forgot about this question. And please ignore my previous comment (which I've removed) - except the `wp_list_comments( $args, get_comments( $args ) );` part.

Comment: Example link is not working.

Comment: You need to temporarily disable threaded (nested) comments - see and try [this](https://pastebin.com/SQsEKy2J).

Comment: thanks, Sally for responding but the link you have provided is not loading, https://pastebin.com/SQsEKy2J

Comment: Emma, it's a Pastebin issue - sometimes it doesn't load a Paste, but try again and it should load.